# Error when clearing cache after creating new Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

**I am using the ORO platform framework.**

Whenever I create a new view and redirect to it in my controller it works.

But when I clear my cache with the `cache:clear`, `rm -rf var/cache/*` or `bin/console --env="prod" cache:clear`. The page stops working, I get the following error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The "CompanyName\Bundle\TestBundle\Controller\TestController::index" controller is not a valid "class::method" string.")
```

I can create a new controller + view with a name that I haven't used before and it will do the same thing.

I can replicate this issue in a new project too.

**My controller:**

```
class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test", name="test")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('test/index.html.twig', [
            'controller' => 'TestController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

**My template:**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello TestController!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<style>
    .example-wrapper { margin: 1em auto; max-width: 800px; width: 95%; font: 18px/1.5 sans-serif; }
    .example-wrapper code { background: #F5F5F5; padding: 2px 6px; }
</style>

<div class="example-wrapper">
    <h1>Hello {{ controller_name }}! ✅</h1>

    This friendly message is coming from:
    <ul>
        <li>Your controller at <code><a href="{{ '/home/name/PhpstormProjects/test_project/src/CompanyName/Bundle/TestBundle/Controller/TestController.php'|file_link(0) }}">src/CompanyName/Bundle/TestBundle/Controller/TestController.php</a></code></li>
        <li>Your template at <code><a href="{{ '/home/name/PhpstormProjects/test_project/templates/test/index.html.twig'|file_link(0) }}">templates/test/index.html.twig</a></code></li>
    </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: what does the `file_link` filter do? Can't seem to find anything about that... (why is there no oro platform tag? ... mh) have you tried asking in their forums, it appears there is more running than in here about that ...

Comment: okay ... oro platform on its own apparently isn't supposed to work, because it "requires an application to initialize and run it" (https://github.com/oroinc/platform) it is suggested to start from the https://github.com/orocrm/platform-application platform application. is that what you did?

Comment: Yes, I installed the application according to the documentation you linked. I tested the template without the ```{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}``` part and that works, but I need that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method in the controller has to end with 'Action', e.g indexAction